# How to read text from an 'Edit' class UI control using pywinauto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

pywinauto and in-general noob here. I am currently working on reading communication back from a robot arm in response to automated commands being sent to it using the terminal window inside the K-IDE program (Kawasaki IDE) using pywinauto. Using win32 in py_inspect I was able to identify the UI control containing the rich text that I want to access (marked with red arrow in screenshot). I want to save the rich_text property (marked in purple) of that UI control to a text file to parse it. How to use pywinauto to achieve this?

Thank you in advance :)

Screenshot: [py_inspect_ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4shfm.png)

Comment: Try using window_text() or texts(). Refer more details here- https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html

Comment: thanks Sachin! window_text() worked

Comment: answer updated with window_text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="win32").connect(title_re='Trying to connect to "Standard 1".*', top_level_only=False)
text = app.window(title_re='Trying to connect to "Standard 1".*', top_level_only=False).window_text()
```

Comment: `rich_text = app.window(title_re='Trying to connect to "Standard 1".*', top_level_only=False).window_text()`

thank you so much Vasily. window_text() instead of rich_text() worked for me.

Comment: Great. Please mark this answer accepted (click gray check box at the left side of answer). This is considered polite on StackOverflow if your problem resolved.